# Почему то мой `z-index` не выводит обьект надо другими?

Tags: html, css

Почему то мой `z-index` не выводит навигацию над другим контентом [site](http://nova-city.kz/ru/).
Мобильное меню при разрешении 780px

```
ul.menu.m_menu{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: сюда добавьте воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C `z-index` все в порядке, подправьте контейнер

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .nav {
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```